# Remove HTML tags in SOLR 5.2.1 highLight snippet being generated

Tags: solr

The requirement is to not remove HTML tags while indexing itself as I require the content with HTML tags later to display the document in the appropriate style.I just want the snippet text that is being generated by the SOLR 5.2.1 highlighting module to return the snippet text without HTML tags.Please suggest if this can be done & how?

PFB relevant part of mannaged-schema.xml:

```
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <processor class="solr.HTMLStripFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
            <str name="typeClass">solr.TextField</str>
      </processor>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

PFB relevant part of solrconfig.xml :

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema">
<processor class="solr.HTMLStripFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="typeClass">solr.TextField</str>
</processor>
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't index to two separate fields - use one for display and one for highlighting?

Comment: @MatsLindh : That adds storage space & increases cost. Also the field I am referring to has very large volume of data & duplicating it isn't viable for me.

Comment: Then strip the HTML in your frontend before displaying it.

Comment: That adds a performance overhead as I said it is huge data. Also, the catch here in that case is snippet will be generated including the HTML tags & the hl.fragmentSize which we give will fetch snippets within the limit. If I process the HTML in frontend then in this case my snippet size becomes too small compared to my fragment size because of the HTML returned by SOLR is now not there in the frontend after processing ! I cant hit SOLR again now to get more length of snippets !